# Getting java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException in webservice

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

I am using Webservice to do currency conversion. I have used already available WSDL "http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?WSDL". Using the above WSDL i have generated web service client. Using that webservice client i am doing currencyconversion. But when i am running my webservice, it is giving me InvocationTargetException. Below is the exception stack trace i am getting.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:56)
Caused by: (404)Not Found
at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.readFromSocket(HTTPSender.java:744)
at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:144)
at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
at NET.webserviceX.www.CurrencyConvertorSoapStub.conversionRate(CurrencyConvertorSoapStub.java:13)
at CurrenyConversionRateValue.main(CurrenyConversionRateValue.java:19)
... 5 more 

Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue.

Below is the code snippet of CurrencyConvertorSoapStub where i am getting exception.

    public double conversionRate(NET.webserviceX.www.Currency fromCurrency, NET.webserviceX.www.Currency toCurrency) throws java.rmi.RemoteException
     {
            if (super.cachedEndpoint == null)
            {
                throw new org.apache.axis.NoEndPointException();
            }
            org.apache.axis.client.Call _call = createCall();
            _call.setOperation(_operations[0]);
            _call.setUseSOAPAction(true);
            _call.setSOAPActionURI("http://www.webserviceX.NET/ConversionRate");
            _call.setEncodingStyle(null);
            _call.setProperty(org.apache.axis.client.Call.SEND_TYPE_ATTR, Boolean.FALSE);
            _call.setProperty(org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.PROP_DOMULTIREFS, Boolean.FALSE);
            _call.setSOAPVersion(org.apache.axis.soap.SOAPConstants.SOAP11_CONSTANTS);
            _call.setOperationName(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://www.webserviceX.NET/", "ConversionRate"));

            setRequestHeaders(_call);
            setAttachments(_call);
     try {       
     java.lang.Object _resp = _call.invoke(new java.lang.Object[] {fromCurrency, toCurrency});

            if (_resp instanceof java.rmi.RemoteException) {
                throw (java.rmi.RemoteException)_resp;
            }
            else {
                extractAttachments(_call);
                try {
                    return ((java.lang.Double) _resp).doubleValue();
                } catch (java.lang.Exception _exception) {
                    return ((java.lang.Double) org.apache.axis.utils.JavaUtils.convert(_resp, double.class)).doubleValue();
                }
            }
      } catch (org.apache.axis.AxisFault axisFaultException) {
      throw axisFaultException;
    }
        }

    }

Can anyone please help me to resolve this exception and to get my webservice work.
```

Comment: `InvocationTargetException`  ususally comes when client cannot reach server .Network related issue.

Answer (score 1):

The above exception got solved.It occured as there is a firewall configuration blocking of CurrencyConversion webservice client. It worked fine after removing the firewall configuration. Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

i am new to webservice but isee when you configure your client you specify a service name defferent from your wsdl name

```
_call.setOperationName(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://www.webserviceX.NET/","ConversionRate"));
```

i think i should be like what you mapped in your wsdl file

Comment: Thanks for reply user2269148.I am also new to webservice. I didnt specify service name manually.I just generated java webservice client from above mentioned WSDL and i used it for currencyconversion. It worked fine in my local. But when i hit the same webservice in another system which has tomcat server it giving me above error. I need to make it work. Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue. Do i need to do any configuration changes like any ports got blocked to hit my webservice?please help me.

Comment: Can anyone Please help me.It is important.

Answer (score 0):

i also got this same exception that is invocation target exception,this exception will come when more time taking process is there in your application,why because webservices are implemented by threads,to solve this on start up only you have to load all the files,means on start up of tomcat we can load all the files.

Answer (score 0):

This exception occurs when you can not access the WebServices ie the URL is not available (blocking FW, misconfiguration, etc.